# How to have a floating label on md-input-container when ng-model is null

Tags: angularjs, html, web, angular-material

What I want to achieve is either this:

[image: Option 1]

Or this:

[image: Option 2]

Current Code:

```
<md-input-container  ng-if="!ctl.module.activeDate" placeholder = "NotSetted">
    <label>Activation Date</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="" disabled></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

This implementation is using Angular Material. I check with the ng-if if the `activeDate` is `null`, if it's not I have another `md-input-container` that gets the value, that is a "workaround" solution, the best way would be to have all of that logic in the same `md-input-container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use placeholders in the input control (not in the input container).
Use `ng-disabled` to disable the control when is not active.
Use `md-placeholder` to set a placeholder in the date picker.

```
<md-input-container  >
        <label>Activation Date</label>
         <md-datepicker  ng-model="ctl.mydate" 
                         ng-disabled="!ctl.module.activeDate" 
                         md-placeholder="Not setted"
          >
         </md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to set a different placeholder for enabled/disabled status, you can use an angular expression :

```
md-placeholder="{{ctl.module.activeDate?'Not setted':'Disabled'}}"
```